# mapStateToProps not executing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux

I want my firebase UI auth to be checked in multiple containers and also redirect to the main page after the authentication is done.

When authentication is done I can see the actions updating and the reducer updating -  but then mapstatetoprops does not do anything with the new reducer state

Loginpage that received props and based on that renders

```js
import React from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import StyledFirebaseAuth from 'react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { signIn, signOut } from '../reducer/actions'
import { auth } from '../firebase'

class LoginPage extends React.PureComponent {

  // Configure FirebaseUI.
  uiConfig = {'FirebaseUI Config'}

  componentDidMount = () => {

    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => { // gets user object on authentication
      console.log('OnAuthStateChanged', user)
      console.log('Check If Props Change in AuthChange', this.props.isauthed)

      if (user) {
        this.props.signIn(user)
      } else {
        this.props.signOut(user)
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log('Check If Props Change in Render', this.props.isauthed)
    if (!this.props.isauthed) {
      return (

        <div>
          <h1>My App</h1>
          <p>Please sign-in:</p>
          <StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={this.uiConfig} firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()} />

        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <Redirect to='/' />
    )
  }
}

export default (LoginPage);
```

JS that should dispatch and update the props

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { signIn, signOut } from '../reducer/actions'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import  LoginPage  from './LoginPage';



const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log('LOGINmapstatetoprops', state.Authed)
    return {
      isauthed: state.Authed.isauthed,
    }
  }
  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    console.log('LOGINmapDISPATCHoprops')
    return bindActionCreators({signIn,signOut},dispatch)
    
  }
  
  
  export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(LoginPage);
```

The reducer

```js
import LoginPage from '../components/LoginPage';
import firebase from 'firebase';

const initialState = {
  isauthed: false,
  error: ''
}


const AuthReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  console.log('this is an action',action)
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'IsSignedIn':
      return state = [
        ...state,
      {
        isauthed: action.payload
      }
    ]
      break;

    case 'IsNotSignedIn':
      return state= [
        ...state,{
        isauthed: action.payload
      }]
      break;
    default: return state
  }
}

export default AuthReducer;
```

This is the actions file

```js
export const signIn = (user) => {
    console.log('this is from actions',user)
    return {
        type: 'isSignedIn',
        payload: true
    }
}

export const signOut = (user) => {
    console.log(user)
    return {
        type: 'isNotSignedIn',
        payload: false
    }
}
```

**Any reason why Mapstatetoprops is idle?**

I do not think a simple scenario like this needs componentwillreceiveprops method

Comment: You should put mapStateToProps in LoginPage component with dispatch and bind it to store, connect to redux. Also you need to import reducer. The way I see it LoginPage is a 'container' component that should be wired up with Redux directly.

Comment: I did that first, Did not work, So just split the code for ease of working  

and why should the reducer be imported? isn't mapstatetoprops already connected to the reducers and store?

Answer (score -1):

there is a problem in the reducer, you should return an object and not an array, change to :

```
case 'IsSignedIn':
  return {
    ...state,
    isauthed: action.payload
}
```

Comment: Nope Not working, it's showing a syntax error
even tried    return {...state, isauthed:action.payload}
Still not working

Comment: can you elaborate whats not working? what do you see when you console.log mapStateToProps ?

Comment: I see all the other logs with the expected value for the isauthed variable, except for the mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps

When user logs it and if (user) returns true the signIn action fires successfully the the reducer also updates the state of isauthed to true

The store is supposed to update and mapStateToprops should update the new set of props instead sits idle doing nothing(no logs)

Comment: but what do you see exactly? do these console.logs work? whats the output?

Comment: this is from actions { Returns User Object}                                                                      
                                AuthReducer.js:11 
this is an action {type: "isSignedIn", payload: true}                                                                LoginPage.js:36 
OnAuthStateChanged Hk {User Object}                                        LoginPage.js:37 
                                  Check If Props Change in AuthChange false      
                                     //props inside function not updating actions.js:2

Comment: Store not updating
console.log (store.getState()), and It does not change from the initial state